# require returning without getting file, intermidtent

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, require

I am trying to read in a file then pass it to another function.  It works about half the time.  I thought `require` was synchronous which is why I'm confused about about what could be happening.

```
...
a["file"] = require "../../file"
thing.install a
...
```

then else where I do,

`console.log a['file']` and it returns `null` about 50% of the time.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: Could you please clarify if you mean requireJS or nodesJs require.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle node.js require

Comment: `require` is synchronous, or you'll have to write you subsequent code that uses the module in a callback function passed to `require`. No one did that. You can use a module right after the require statement. That's the point. Check you code to see if you modified `a` somewhere.

Comment: @Alexis you're going to need to show more code for us to help with this, we can't see where it might be modified.  if you put the console.log immediately after the require does it display the value every time?